# 64 bit net-snmp download

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to install net-snmp binaries and landed to below page from their website -

https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/

I am not able to see the 64 bit installer - is it that net-snmp binaries for 64 bits Win 7 OS is not available? Do we need to build it then from source?

Comment: Its Windows build has been outdated for years. So building from source should be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the last binaries put there date from 2011.

That area [simply hasn't been maintained](https://serverfault.com/q/283922/72833).

The FAQ [equivocates on this matter](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/FAQ.html#Are_there_binaries_available_).

Build from source.